# React final form multipart data

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-final-form

I am using [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) for handling form data in my component.
How can I submit multipart form data using `react-final-form`?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue raised in react-final-form for the same. You can refer the same [here](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/92)

Answer (score 0):

More recent answer would be to use React Final form Wizard. Example can be found here https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/wizard You can have an array of steps/pages

```
const steps = [
{ property1: 'some name', property2: 'some name' },
{ property1: 'some name', property2: 'some name' } ];
```

Then feed that into the Wizard

```
 <Wizard
    onSubmit={onSubmit} // onSubmit can live in your parent component as well or however you choose to set it up
    steps={steps}
 />
```